# Slitaz prevent tux login without password

Tags: linux, slitaz

I am building a small demo distro with some php / mysql code and looking at a quick boot, small footprint headless distro. Slitaz works well but I am stuck at a minor spot which I have not been able to find answers in the documentation. I tried to register on the site, but its several days and I haven't received registration info.

All I want to achieve is to ensure tux user is not auto-logged-in after entering user name. Using passwd did not help and the prompt does not even go to asking for password but logs in tux just entering username.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Many thanks for your comment Thomas. tux is a default user in slitaz.
The base Slitaz is 8 mb ISO. I managed to get Apache 2, PHP 5.4, MariaDB, SSH, Git, Nano all in under 70mb zip VM.

I researched the topic again.. spent some hours analysing the boot process.
For anyone arriving here, comment out a line in bootopt.sh
    `# passwd -d $USER >/dev/null`
by adding a # (hash) at the beginning of the line. This line was null-ing the passwd entry for tux. The boot process looks a bit convulated.. why would password need to be set to null?

The only other option was to use TinyCore, which I had problems with getting the later versions of PHP and could never get gcc to compile anything. I did get a Debian 7 working but the zip is 700MB and a bit tough for me to transport, hence the struggle with Slitaz :).

Comment: An empty password field allows password-less login. Not a bad idea for a live system starting from cd. There is no way to set a secure password on a public cd anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar wih Slitaz, but these are the places to look that pop up in my mind

- Is `tux` a special user (for example the first created)? Try to create a new user; what are the results?
- Is `tux` member of a sucpicious group?
- Is `tux` or one of it's groups whitelisted in PAM (`/etc/pam.d`)
- You said headless, but from some screenshots on the net Slitaz looks gui capable. If you log in graphically, figure out what the login manager is and check it's documentation.
- Try http://forum.slitaz.org/

Comment: Yes, it has a roughly 35mb ISO with a basic GUI, which is very interesting!